# dynamic text wrapping for labels

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, graph-visualization, cytoscape

Can I set dynamic text widths for my node labels? Width and height of the nodes are changing so I don't want to set a fixed value like `"text-max-width": "100px"` as a style

Comment: You can set `text-max-width` to any dynamic css property like `75%, 50vw, 50vh, 1rem, etc..`. Did you mean that by dynamic text width or do you want to set that width depending of the nodes width?

Comment: Depending on the node width. I want to fit labels to nodes. I didn't know any CSS property is valid there

Comment: I tried **mapping** feature of cytoscape style.  `"text-max-width": "mapData(title.length, 0, 100, 0px, 100px)" ` it seems like not working